# 24,464 rep in 2 weeks?

Tags: support, reputation, new-users

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3730911/user3730911) user in "new users" > "reputation". It is shown that he is member for only 14 days. Also tag scores are broken. And some of his answers are from 2011. How can it be possible? If account merging occured, why tag scores weren't updared?

Comment: Any other issues I might have with some of your behavior aside; I am quite impressed with your ability to find really strange things!

Comment: @Andrew'saUnitato THX. The thing is, I should have a rep source to compensate my down voted posts. :D

Comment: Well, this and your last question have gained you quite a bit more than your previous one lost you! :-)

Comment: @Andrew'saUnitato Weeeell, looks like... you are right.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

For reasons I won't go into out of respect for the privacy of the person involved, that account had to be re-created. This is a bit of a dodgy process, and so some information associated with it is inconsistent.

Comment: Josh, let's be friends?!?! :D

Comment: If the purpose was to delete any trace to the old account (i.e. new identity, starting with a clean slate) let me know and I can delete my answer, Google Cache will also be updated soon. Otherwise, well, not my business. :)

Comment: @Sha MHAHAHA I won't let you to delete your answer!!

Comment: @nicael I'm sure Shog here can still do it. :)

Comment: Not exactly, @Sha - but leaving that information out of the open is probably not a bad idea. Removed.

Comment: @Sha ARGRHGRHGRHGHGHHHHH!!!!!!

Comment: @nicael now start working hard to earn 10k here then you can see it again. lol (even with all your tricks it will take you a while, if you won't get yourself suspended while trying :D)

Comment: @Sha [I don't like to earn much rep](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2963652/nicael). Lol :D. Well, a simple trick: `myrep*=100`

Comment: Maybe you'll unlock [Suspension till 2027](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251212/suspension-till-2027)? I bet not to abuse edits, if any abuse,  suspend me till 2027.

Comment: @Sha I still remember that I have to work hard to see it again :)