# Should moderator diamonds be inside or outside the highlight box?

Tags: bug, design, moderators, original-poster

In comments, moderators have their diamonds in the OP rectangle:

> [image: innie]

And in the review (suggested edits), mods have their diamonds outside the blue OP background highlight rectangle:

> [image: outie]

Of course, it Doesn't Really Matter At All, but it *is* a small discrepancy (I am not saying that in the review, OP rectangles have a bigger padding).

Comment: IMO should always be outside, as it's not part of the display name.

Comment: Has anyone ever told you you'd have an ruddy *great* QA engineer? You keep finding the oddest things wrong.

Comment: @Mart yes, you have told.

Comment: @Mart Ah, no, [also Andrew Barber](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234485/24-464-rep-in-2-weeks#comment771096_234485).

Comment: @nicael: I am quite serious. The best QA engineers are the ones that can creatively futz everything and find stuff like this. Go talk to big software companies that have QA roles.

Comment: @Mart yeah, but with my [100 years](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239619/new-smarter-profile-creation-and-syncing/239626#239626)... what for? I have quite a quiet life... ah.

Comment: Put it inside. Now pull it outside.  Now inside.  Now outside.  Now inside.  Now... And now I've lost interest.

Comment: @Won't too fast. not good.

Comment: @wont and shake it all about? Do the okey cokey an' you turn around, that's what it's all about!

Comment: I don't quite understand what your asking.

Comment: @x-x see the screenshots. In the top one the diamond is inside the blue background and in the bottom screenshot, the diamond is outside the background. OP is asking to make it consistent. :)

Comment: Oh so there is no way for someone like me to do anything?

Answer (score 4):

Outside. Not only is it not part of the display name and should be separated from it, the solid blue diamond on the blue background is hard to see at a glance.

However, it should still be blue to make it obvious that it's associated with the user.

Comment: +1 Outside is right, as it's not part of the name.

Comment: @Frank: How? It's a "bug" post, not a feature-request or discussion.

Comment: Users give opinions and views on discussions and feature requests, this post was a bug report submitted by OP, please refer the tags @Frank. For bugs, devs reply status completed, or status declined, as per the format of SE http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bug

Comment: @Inf also [tag:status-bydesign]

Comment: Yes @Frank, the point being that your +1 comment and reason was not so fit for this answer on a bug report. It's obviously right, that's why it's a "bug".

Comment: @Inf Well I liked his answer, so +1.